# Qt/C++ пропадает оформление меню: File, Edit etc при смене темы оформления ОС:

Tags: c++, qt

Уважаемые Форумчане! Не могли бы вы подсказать мне с такой проблемой: с помощью QStyle создан стиль оформления интерфейса программы, однако, мной было замечено, что при смене темы оформления операционной системы (цвета фона в случае Windows 10)сбрасывается этот самый стиль с верхнего меню File,Edit etc, есть ли возможность как-то устранить эту огреху?

Comment: приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Извините, но, увы, в том-то и сложность, что не могу(